# Complex interpolation on an FPGA

Tags: signal-processing, fpga, hdl

I have a problem in that I need to implement an algorithm on an FPGA that requires a large array of data that is too large to fit into block or distributed memory. The array contains complex fixed-point values, and it turns out that I can do a good job by reducing the total number of stored values through decimation and then linearly interpolating the interim values on demand.

Though I have DSP blocks (and so fixed-point hardware multipliers) which could be used trivially for real and imaginary part interpolation, I actually want to do the interpolation on the amplitude and angle (of the polar form of the complex number) and then convert the result to real-imaginary form. The data can be stored in polar form if it improves things.

I think my question boils down to this: How should I quickly convert between polar complex numbers and real-imaginary complex numbers (and back again) on an FPGA (noting availability of DSP hardware)? The solution need not be exact, just close, but be speed optimised. Alternatively, better strategies are gladly received!

edit: I know about cordic techniques, so this would be how I would do it in the absence of a better idea. Are there refinements specific to this problem I could invoke?

Another edit: Following from @mbschenkel's question, and some more thinking on my part, I wanted to know if there were any known tricks specific to the problem of polar interpolation.

In my case, the dominant variation between samples is a phase rotation, with a slowly varying amplitude. Since the sampling grid is known ahead of time and is regular, one trick could be to precompute some complex interpolation factors. So, for two complex values `a` and `b`, if we wish to find `(N-1)` intermediate equally spaced values, we can precompute the factor

```
scale = (abs(b)/abs(a))**(1/N)*exp(1j*(angle(b)-angle(a)))/N)
```

and then find each intermediate value iteratively as `val[n] = scale * val[n-1]` where `val[0] = a`.

This works well for me as I need the samples in order and I compute them all. For small variations in amplitude (i.e. abs(b)/abs(a) ~= 1) and 0 < n < N, `(abs(b)/abs(a))**(n/N)` is approximately linear (though linear is not necessarily better).

The above is all very good, but still results in a complex multiplication. Are there other options for approximating this? I'm interested in resource and speed constraints, not accuracy. I know I can do the rotation with CORDIC, but still need a pair of multiplications for the scaling, so I'm adding lots of complexity and resource usage for potentially limited results. I don't really have a feel for the convergence of CORDIC, so perhaps I just truncate early, or use lots of resources to converge quickly.

Comment: So, essentially you're looking for a sin/cos calculation that's faster than CORDIC? Maybe it would also help to know what kind of processing you want to apply to the data, why you need to convert to cartesian and why decimation and interpolation works (no high-frequency content?).

Comment: @mbschenkel I've added some more thoughts based on your comment and more thinking on my part.

Comment: CORDIC is the best solution for this kind of problem. You haven't made a good case for why you want to avoid it. If you have to apply the scaling, the hardware multipliers are there to be used. If you have them available then use them. It is also possible to defer the scale correction to some later stage or pre-apply it before the CORDIC operation. This could be a no-cost step if it can be merged with another necessary operation. CORDIC will converge for angles between +/- 99.7 degrees. If you need to cover the whole complex plane then you need to make adjustments for quadrants 2&3.

Comment: From what you're describing, the sampled signal is sinusoidal. Does it have a constant frequency? Do you really need access to the entire dataset later on or could you just do the whole processing in real-time? Would it make sense to use external RAM ?

Comment: @mbschenkel It's not sinusoidal - though I suppose (very) locally it could be modelled as such. The broader point is that it's massively oversampled, so interpolation is eminently sensible, but relying on it being sinusoidal would be a mistake. I'll be using external RAM as well. This is basically to reduce the bandwidth in shuffling data from external RAM to the local block RAM, which is a dominant factor in the algorithm at the moment.